# Android custom listview with checkbox issue

Tags: android

right now I am developing an Android app for my class project. This app will be used for uploading files to Yahoo! Web hosting server. Now, I am having problem with custom listview with checkbox for my "FileBrowserActivity". The problem is my checkbox always get unchecked every time I click a listview item - a directory/folder to see its content. It seems the checkbox state never get saved. I tried to use boolean checkedState array and ViewHolder class, but I have no luck. Here are the link to the screenshots to explain the problem. I hope it helps:
1. http://imgur.com/is43t29. In this screenshot, I checked the 2 checkboxes for the last two items in my listview.
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pznT4.jpg. After, the step above, I clicked the "Ringtone" folder, and selected all three items inside it.

(I can't post more than 2 links. I'll post the 3rd one in the comment).

Here are my codes:
1. This is my custom adapter class

```
public class FileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListDescription>{
private Context context;
private boolean[] checkBoxStates;
private int id;
private List<ListDescription> items;

public FileArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,List<ListDescription> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.id = resource;
    this.items = objects;
    this.checkBoxStates = new boolean[objects.size()];
}

public ListDescription getItem(int i){
    return items.get(i);
}

private class ViewHolder{
    TextView listItemTxt;
    TextView listSubItemTxt;
    CheckBox cb;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if(v == null){
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(id, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.listItemTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(com.example.shareit.R.id.fileListItem);
        holder.listSubItemTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(com.example.shareit.R.id.fileListSubItem);
        holder.cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(com.example.shareit.R.id.checkBox1);
        v.setTag(holder);

        /*holder.cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox c = (CheckBox) v;
                ListDescription ldes = (ListDescription) c.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Clicked on checkbox: " + ldes.getName(), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ldes.setSelected(c.isChecked());
            }
        });*/
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    final ListDescription o = items.get(position);

    if(o != null){
        /*TextView t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(com.example.shareit.R.id.fileListItem);
        TextView t2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(com.example.shareit.R.id.fileListSubItem);
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(com.example.shareit.R.id.checkBox1);*/


        //if(t1 != null){
        if(holder.listItemTxt != null){
            //t1.setText(o.getName());
            holder.listItemTxt.setText(o.getName());
        }
        //if(t2 != null){
        if(holder.listSubItemTxt != null){
            //t2.setText(o.getData());
            holder.listSubItemTxt.setText(o.getData());
        }

        holder.cb.setChecked(checkBoxStates[position]);
        if(o.getData().equalsIgnoreCase("folder") || o.getData().equalsIgnoreCase("parent directory")){
            //cb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.cb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //holder.cb.setTag(o);
        }
        else{
            //cb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.cb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //holder.cb.setTag(o);
        }

        holder.cb.setTag(position);
    }
    return v;
}

}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix my problem?

Thanks

Comment: 3. http://imgur.com/jbApuG8. Then, I went back to the parent directory, "sdcard", and the checkboxes that I selected in step one is unchecked.

Comment: Why dont you add in the ListDescription a boolean if is checked or not, and in your code you set your checkbox doing items.get(position).isChecked()

Comment: The checked state is indeed not saved because the adapter & listview & .. assume that you will do that manually if you need that state. They just keep track as long as they have to display it.

Comment: @JpCrow: I actually have a private boolean isChecked variable in my "ListDescription" class, but I didn't implement any function for that. I'll try your suggestion. Thx

Comment: @AlexK: Hey, yeah I rarely use stackoverflow, thats why I don't really know what to do. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: @zangetsKid sure. it's just a friendly reminder. Plus it rewards the people who worked hard to answer your questions!